# Replaced ProgressDialog with ProgressBar, does not show half the time

Tags: java, android, progress-bar

Title is not great but I am replacing `ProgressDialog` with `ProgressBar` in my android application. After implementing it in my `ProjectsFragment` class, I run the app and I see the default `ProgressBar` load while the app loads data from my database. This works great. Then I replace `ProgressDialog` in the `ProjectViewActivity` and none of the `ProgressBars` show anymore. I can't tell if they work and they're just not showing or if I broke it by adding the `ProgressBar` to the parent activity. My other thought was that maybe the app has cached the data and it's so fast to load that `ProgressBar` doesn't even appear but after deleting the cache and all app data, it still won't show.

Here is my code from the `ProjectsFragment` class where it worked:

```
loading = new ProgressBar(getActivity());
public void loadProjects() {
    loading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    db.collection("users").document(user.getUid()).collection("projects").get() //Get all projects from selected user
        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener < QuerySnapshot > () {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                projects.clear(); //Clear before reloading
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot: queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                    projects.add(documentSnapshot.toObject(ProjectItem.class));
                }
                refreshRecycler();
            }
        });
}

public void refreshRecycler() {
        adapter = new DashboardProjectAdapter(projects, getContext()); //Create adapter with list of projects
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter); //Assign adapter to recycler view
        adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new DashboardProjectAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(int position) {
                String projectID;
                projectID = projects.get(position).getProjectID();
                String projectName;
                projectName = projects.get(position).getProjectName();
                Intent openProjectView = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), ProjectViewActivity.class); //?
                openProjectView.putExtra("projectID", projectID);
                openProjectView.putExtra("projectName", projectName);
                startActivity(openProjectView);
            }
        });
        loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Here is my code from the `ProjectViewActivity` where I have initiated it twice and then it shows nowhere (sorry about the length of code added, I'm just not sure where I went wrong):

```
ProgressBar loading;
public void loadTasks() {
    loading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    //Get tasks from database and load into ArrayList
    db.collection("users").document(user.getUid()).collection("projects").document(projectID).collection("tasks").get()
        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener < QuerySnapshot > () {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                //Clear list
                allTasks.clear();
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot: queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                    allTasks.add(documentSnapshot.toObject(TaskItem.class));
                }
                //Clear lists
                tasksToDo.clear();
                tasksInProgress.clear();
                tasksInReview.clear();
                tasksComplete.clear();
                //Sort tasks into respective lists
                for (TaskItem task: allTasks) {
                    switch (task.getStatus()) {
                        case 0:
                            tasksToDo.add(task);
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            tasksInProgress.add(task);
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            tasksInReview.add(task);
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            tasksComplete.add(task);
                            break;
                        default:
                            Toast.makeText(ProjectViewActivity.this, "A database error has occurred, please contact a Developer", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
                setupAdapters();
                loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                displayToDo();
            }
        });
}

//This is the method called from the ProjectReviewViewAdapter after a tasked is marked complete
public void loadTasksReview() {
        loading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        //Get tasks from database and load into ArrayList
        db.collection("users").document(user.getUid()).collection("projects").document(projectID).collection("tasks").get()
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener < QuerySnapshot > () {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                    //Clear list
                    allTasks.clear();
                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot: queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                        allTasks.add(documentSnapshot.toObject(TaskItem.class));
                    }
                    //Clear lists
                    tasksToDo.clear();
                    tasksInProgress.clear();
                    tasksInReview.clear();
                    tasksComplete.clear();
                    //Sort tasks into respective lists
                    for (TaskItem task: allTasks) {
                        switch (task.getStatus()) {
                            case 0:
                                tasksToDo.add(task);
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                tasksInProgress.add(task);
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                tasksInReview.add(task);
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                tasksComplete.add(task);
                                break;
                            default:
                                Toast.makeText(ProjectViewActivity.this, "A database error has occurred, please contact a Developer", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                    setupAdapters();
                    loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(layout, "Task accepted and moved to complete.", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                    snackbar.show();
                    displayForReview();
                }
            });
```

Any help is appreciated, I can explain any step of my code if you need. Again, it shows no errors in Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

You first of need to add the progressbar to your main layout or a the layout you want it in for it to appear

```
  main.addView(loading);
```

you can also set layout parameters if you wish to edit its layout parameters eg position